# How to disable Swipe on Side Menu in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

How do i disable swipe on side menu in Ionic 2 ?

I'v tried this inside my constructor in HomePage:

```
this.menu.swipeEnable(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I managed to **disable the side menu** inside HomePage:

```
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.menu.swipeEnable(false, 'left');
    this.menu.enable(false, 'left');
  }
```

I had to wait for the **View to load** and then disabling Swipe on menu by **passing 'left' parameter**. The left parameter is because the menu is on the left side. For me passing an **menu id** did not work...

Answer (score 1):

The HTML way, according to [Ionic Menu documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/menu/Menu/#input-properties):

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" [swipeEnabled]="false">
  ...
</ion-menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

So turn off the sidebar menu

```
this.menuCtrl.swipeEnable(false, 'left');
this.menuCtrl.enable(false, 'left');
```

So you activate the sidebar menu

```
this.menuCtrl.swipeEnable(true, 'left');
this.menuCtrl.enable(true, 'left');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the menu reference:

```
this.menu.swipeEnable(false, 'menu');
```

alternatively, try adding it to the life cycle event

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
     this.menu.swipeEnable(false, 'menu');
}
```